# Why isn't my COM class a Singleton?

Tags: c#, com, ipc, unmanaged

For some reason, 2 objects are being created when they should be a Singleton.

I have a class Bridge whose purpose is to communicate from one application to another. The first app, App1, creates the bridge via COM and immediately calls the bridge's initialize method:

```
bool IBridge.Initialize(ref App1 theApp)
{
       if (theApp != null)
       {
            this.refToApp = theApp;
            log("Got bridge from App1");
            //spin up App2
            Process.Start([path to App2]);
       }
       else
       {
           log("theApp was null");
       }
       return true;
}
```

The Bridge class uses a singleton pattern but has a public default constructor so that COM will work properly with it but users of this class have to respect the fact that it's a singleton by only accessing it using the instance property.

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[ProgId("[id that App1 uses to instantiate class]")]
public class Bridge : IBridge
{
    private static readonly _instance;

    public static COMBridge Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null){
                _instance = new Bridge();
            }
            return _instance
        }
    }

  public Bridge()
  {
       log("Called default constructor");
       if (_instance == null)
       {
            _instance = this;
       }
  }

 ...
```

However when App2 starts, it calls the getter for Instance and the constructor is called again. This is troublesome because the Bridge is a communication component and I need these two apps to talk to each other using the bridge.

Any tips?

Comment: Suppose two threads/processes executing `if(_instance == null)` at the same time, what happens?

Comment: Is the com object is implemented as an assembly (.dll) ? If so, what make you think that the two processes will both be looking the same instance of the com object?

Comment: @L.B I don't think this is a threading issue because the calls are far apart. Like I log the calls to the constructor and they're called over a second in time apart from one another so I don't believe that's the issue here (I do recognize that's it's poor code but I just need it working to start!)

Comment: @user957902 I think this is my issue. The strange thing is that previously, App2 was written in VB and it would call a `CreateObject(progId)` method which would return the same object. Now I'm writing App2 in C# and it seems to work differently

Comment: FYI, that singleton isn't thread safe. Go do a quick google search for methods of creating thread-safe singletons in C#.

Comment: As soon as you make your class [ComVisible(true)] with a public constructor then the game is up, the client code can always create a new object.  You could only enforce the contract by throwing an exception in your constructor if _instance isn't null.  

This is not terribly likely to spin the client programmer's propeller.  A more usable scheme is to **not** make your class [ComVisible], only the interface.  And provide *another* [ComVisible] class that has a factory method that returns the one-and-only interface reference.  You need to think about the lifetime.

Comment: @Hans I like the idea of throwing the exception if it's not null. Here's what I think is going on: App1 creates the Bridge object in its process. I thought since I was writing it in C# that this object would be managed by the .NET runtime and therefore when I call that static `Instance` property of Bridge in App2 (written in C#, .NET), that it would find App1's instance. However it seems like that is not the case and these two separate processes don't 'see' the same static objects.

Comment: Erm, wait, it wasn't clear to me before that these are different processes.  .NET only supports creating an in-process COM server easily, every process gets its own copy of it and there is no sharing at all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the com object is configured to be an Out of Process com object (I am assuming this because it looks like it used to work that way from VB) then you have to jump through some hoops to get it to activate as an out of process object. by default .Net will load the object as an In Process com object, which means that every process will have its own copy of the object. Per the artical [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/hosting-net-dll-out-process)

> If you try using your COM object now, you might discover that it’s still loaded into the client’s process. The reason is that you have to tell COM you’re interested in out-of-process activation. If you’re using C/C++, pass CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER as the dwClsContext argument of the CoCreateInstance function. If you’re using C#/VB.NET, you’ll have to P/Invoke into CoCreateInstance for this.

Comment: So I take it that COM objects can be used to do IPC? That is, App1 is in its own process, creates the COM object bridge. App2 is in a separate process and needs to talk to the same Bridge and in process 1.

Comment: Yes it can, but it has to be an out of process COM object to do that. The COM object actually exists in a separate 3rd process in that case. That process does not even have to be on the same computer.